How may I generate Lennard-Jones parameters for modeling CVD growth?
Could anyone kindly provide me with any information on how to generate the Lennard-Jones parameters for tungsten hexacarbonyl and hydrogen selenide when modeling CVD of WSe2 growth. Thank you.
